# Why and how to set multiple classes in sass?

Tags: css, sass

I am using `Sass`, and I see many multiple classes in html file, such as:

```
<a href="#" class="button white">a link</a>
```

Why should I use multiple classes?

And it seems that the `css` should be:

```
.button {
    font-size: 12px;
}

.button.white {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

but why this doesn't work:

```
.button {
    font-size: 12px;

    .white {
        background-color: #fff;
    }
}
```

so how can I use `sass` simplify the `css` file?

Comment: You'd use multiple classes for the same reason that you'd use multiple classes in CSS: e.g. maybe you want this element to have the `button` and `white` classes, but you'd want another element to have the `button` and `blue` classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is that the nesting is corresponding with a smilier nesting in html, i.e

```
<div class="button">
    <div class="white">This would get a background of #fff</div>
</div>
```

To get what you want, you should can use & as a alias to the selector of the parent:

```
.button {
    font-size: 12px;

    &.white {
        background-color: #fff;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below SCSS code.

```
.button {
    font-size: 12px;

    &.white {
        background-color: #fff;
    }
}
```

CSS Output

```
.button {
    font-size: 12px;
}
.button.white{
    background-color: #fff;
}
```